# Dismiss VC very slow due to autolayout and lots of subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a scrollview loaded with lots of subviews, and for reasons I won't go into, I opted against `cell` re-use and a `UITableView`. It works well, save for a little initial main thread lag when the view is populated. However, every time a VC `"on top"` is dismissed (`e.g. after presenting a modal overtop`), there is a significant delay (2-3 seconds). I ran it through the profiler and the stack trace delves very deeply into IOS / Autolayout, as seen in the attached image.

The code seems to go into
 `NSLayoutConstraint("+0x06 calll               "-[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:]+0x0b")`.

Is there anything I can do to bypass this apparent re-application of constraints?

[image: dat stack]

Comment: IOS 7? Have tried on IOS 6?

Comment: IOS 7. Will see if I can target iOS 6 and report back.

Comment: Issue present on iOS 6 as well.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing, did you find a solution? I was using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: and begin/endUpdates. Changing that to reloadData fixes it.

Comment: No solution yet. Using reloadData exclusively, so no such luck there.

Comment: You need to show some code. How you layout your cells (`layoutSubviews`), how you layout your view controller (`viewWillLayoutSubivews`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews`), etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Why your scroll view's performance is poor

From looking at your trace, the root of your problem begins when transitioning back: you spend 80%+ of your time in `-[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:]`. This method immediately adds the view you transition to back into the view hierarchy (the `-addSubview:` call following), which necessitates a full Auto Layout pass.

I'm not aware of any way to force the normal iOS view controller transition system into keeping your old view around in the background, so to speak, so as to avoid this Auto Layout pass. (Such an approach might actually run into its own set of problems, if multiple views stack up offscreen and start to cause memory pressure.)

#### Speeding up Auto Layout in your existing structure

Despite the above, you can try to optimize your Auto Layout pass in a couple ways. First, rework your scroll view to have fewer subviews. Apple's developer tech support has also sometimes recommended flattening your view hierarchy; causing Auto Layout to do less recursion can sometimes be helpful. (See, for example, the performance tests performed by [Florian Kugler](http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/21/auto-layout-performance-on-ios) and [Martin Pilkington](http://pilky.me/view/36).)

You should also always ensure that a constraint is installed on the deepest possible view within your hierarchy, while still being on the common ancestor of the two views it relates to. For example, if view A has subviews B and C, you would want a constraint referencing only view C installed on view C, not view A; however, a constraint relating B and C would need to exist on A. This is a good guideline for *all* Auto Layout work, not just in this particular case; the deeper a constraint is installed in the hierarchy, the faster the underlying solver can work at any particular level.

#### Switching your approach

UITableView is able to avoid this problem by providing a sort of break in the Auto Layout system: the table view can position properly with constraints, then use its own delegate methods (such as `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`) and some internal layout magic to run Auto Layout individually for each cell, without requiring the entire view to be laid out all at once. Regular UIScrollViews do not have the luxury of this optimization.

I know you said you have reasons for not adopting a UITableView here, but you might consider revisiting those reasons. You can see some very significant speed improvements from switching to UITableView and implementing the delegate method `-tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`, which lets you short-circuit a lot of Auto Layout calculations at view load time and defer them until the point you're about to scroll a new cell onscreen. There has been some fairly significant experimentation done in this direction, both [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) and by others in the community. (A quick search for "UITableView Auto Layout height" will turn up dozens of results.)

#### Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. You've convinced me there won't be a trivial solution -- I will consider adopting some of the suggestions above and worst case, attempting a switch back to a UITableView (UITableView black magic causes me problems in other areas of the application, but would save me in this situation)

Comment: This is a good answer. The only thing that I would add is this: depending on what your actual code/view setup looks like, you might be able to use an offscreen view hierarchy to do the Auto Layout calculations once, and then cache the calculated frames for all of the views after you do one layout pass. Then, for the real view hierarchy you display onscreen, you set the frames manually (without Auto Layout or any constraints) based on each view's corresponding offscreen Auto Layout counterpart. Obviously this will require some re-engineering, but it would definitely solve your main issue.